# is addSubview by default (0,0)

Tags: ios

Hello I have added a view to my viewcontroller and all I did was call the addSubview and by default it is setting it (0,0) I never set these coordinates I just wanted to confirm it is 0,0 the default coordinates when you dont specify any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subview is added at a size and position determined by its frame or autolayout constraints. If you never assign it a frame or constraints its frame is `.zero`.

Comment: its an AdView but im not using constraints i just called self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
      initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

  [self addBannerViewToView:self.bannerView];

Comment: But you didn't ask anything about GADBannerView in your question. Still, if you call `initWithAdSize` you are not assigning an `origin` to the `frame` so it's no surprise if the `origin` is `.zero`.